# create javascript array from complex json object

Tags: javascript, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript “For …in” with Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays)

I am pretty new to JSON. I have searched for an answer on stackoverflow but am kind of confused so I'm not sure if I've stumbled upon a solution or not. So, I decided to post my code and needs in hopes for a solution that I can apply.

If there is already a solution that exists, I apologize in advance and can only imagine that I just didn't understand what I was looking at.

I have a json object which looks like this:

```
{
"0": [
    {
        "uguid": "11111-11111-11111",
        "username": "username",
        "password": "",
        "first_name": "User1",
        "last_name": "Name1",
        "title": "title here",
        "group_guid": "g0001",
        "force_pw_reset": "f",
        "permissions": [
            [
                "p1",
                "p2",
                "p3",
                "p4",
                "p5"
            ]
        ],
        "active": "t",
        "t_access": [
            []
        ],
        "i_access": [
            []
        ],
        "c_access": [
            []
        ],
        "class_name": "class name",
        "method": "method name"
    }
],
"1": [
    {
        "uguid": "22222-22222-2222",
        "username": "username2",
        "password": "",
        "first_name": "User2",
        "last_name": "Name2",
        "title": "",
        "g_guid": "g0002",
        "force_pw_reset": "f",
        "permissions": [
            [
                "p1",
                "p2",
                "p3",
                "p4",
                "p5",
                "p6"
            ]
        ],
        "active": "t",
        "t_access": [
            []
        ],
        "i_access": [
            []
        ],
        "c": [
          [
              "c0001"
          ]
        ],
        "class_name": "class name",
        "method": "method name"
    }
],
"2": [
    {
        "u_guid": "33333-33333-33333",
        "username": "username3",
        "password": "",
        "first_name": "User3",
        "last_name": "Pass3",
        "title": "",
        "gguid": "g0003",
        "force_pw_reset": "f",
        "permissions": [
            [
                "p1",
                "p2",
                "p3"
            ]
        ],
        "active": "t",
        "t_access": [
            [
              "t0001"
            ]
        ],
        "i_access": [
            []
        ],
        "c_access": [
            []
        ],
        "class_name": "class name",
        "method": "method name"
    }
]
```

}

What I want to be able to do is iterate over this (or any) json and create an array. I would need to be able to recursively iterate when/where needed. Also, hopefully whatever the solution is would work with whatever json object that gets passed to the function.

UPDATE: I guess I should have mentioned I want to create a *javascript* array if that makes any difference. Also, I am taking a json string and using json_parse() from douglas crockford to get an object. I want to take that object (shown) and create the javascript array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert an object

```
obj = {
   "0": ...,
   "1": ...,
   ...
}
```

to an array, I'd suggest this :

```
var a = [];
for (var i=0; typeof obj[i] != 'undefined'; i++) a[i] = obj[i];
```

Comment: I found this link but wasn't sure it was iterating over the json I have: ackoverflow.com/questions/7707646/loop-through-complex-json-object